# IntellJ : Test being ignored cause it does exists in server

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests

The issue is related to The intellj plugin : Illuminated Cloud (for SFA), the issue is when i make some local changes and want to run some test i keep getting

```
Test method mehod_name was never reported as completed. Perhaps it doesn't exist on the server?
```

but when i deploy to the server and then run the tests, it works fine with no issues.

so how do i run the tests locally without first deploying to the server?

Comment: Intellij's `Illuminated cloud` or any plugin related to Salesforce does not support local changes to run the test, you will have to deploy it to salesforce before running the test.

Comment: i had really hoped we could run without deploying...Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of your development environment, Apex only runs on an org; there is no "local" execution, ever. Apex is a proprietary language with an entirely proprietary runtime environment (built into the Salesforce platform).

This is different to Jest tests (for example) which are written in and against JavaScript, where an execution environment exists locally. JS is an open spec language with many runtime environment implementations available.